# Installing a custom Processing algorithm for all users

Tags: qgis, qgis-processing, windows

QGIS is installed for all users on a Windows machine.

A custom Processing algorithm stored in a file named `alg.py` should be made available to all those users by storing it in that QGIS installation. It should not be installed to the users' profiles but in the central QGIS installation directory.

Where do I have to place that file?

Answer (score 2):

The quick and dirty solution would be to add your script to the existing QGIS processing provider:

1. Edit your script `alg.py`:

   - add the import: `from processing.algs.qgis.QgisAlgorithm import QgisAlgorithm` at the top of the file
   - Change the class heritage from: `class ExampleAlgo(QgsProcessingFeatureBasedAlgorithm/QgsProcessingAlgorithm)` to `class ExampleAlgo(QgisFeatureBasedAlgorithm/QgisAlgorithm)`
2. Put the file `alg.py` here:

   - `C:\Program Files\QGIS x.x.x\apps\qgis\python\plugins\processing\algs\qgis`
3. Edit the qgis provider to add your processing algo (`C:\Program Files\QGIS x.x.x\apps\qgis\python\plugins\processing\algs\qgis\QgisAlgorithmProvider.py`):

   - add the class name of your script (`ExampleAlgo()`) in the list of algorithms inside the function `getAlgs(self)`

A better solution would be to create your own custom provider, [here](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1YdlDvyjrfO1ww3aIJEgrtfenSXYimLKX/view?usp=sharing) is a template to extract inside `C:\Program Files\QGIS x.x.x\apps\qgis\python\plugins\processing` it will override some files to add the included custom provider so QGIS automatically loads it at launch. Also, it creates a `custom` folder where you can add all the algorithm scripts you want, it's done the same way as above when I explained how to add it to the QGIS processing provider but to the Custom Provider.

[image]

I would just add that this might break from one version to the next if the behavior of the processing handling changes (It works on Windows and QGIS 3.28.2, no way for me to know if it will work on all versions). And, it would need a very good reason to be done this way since it is much easier to just add the scripts to the user profiles that aren't linked to a singular version of QGIS and it doesn't require modifying QGIS python files.